# How open a url from a Javascript Windows Universal application in a browser window?

Tags: javascript, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

How open a url from a Javascript Windows Universal Application application in a browser like Edge or Chrome?

Using the "open" JS function (window.open) opens the url inside the app window. I would like to open it on Edge or the default windows 10 configured browser.

Comment: Perfect @RaymondChen .Write an answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [LaunchUriAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync.aspx) method.

```
Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(   // note that .launchUriAsync() is lowercase
    new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/"))
.then(function (success) {
    if (success) {
        // the launch succeeded
    } else {
        // the launch failed
    }
});
```

Comment: .LaunchUriAsync() is lowercase, .launchUriAsync()

Comment: Is this method a async method? Because I execution is not going inside the 'then' block. And it is not giving any error. And not even throwing.